# Rails Docker breaks with an update to Rack 2.0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems, docker-compose

I have a Docker instance with running Rails with SOLR 
Everything was running great then I had to update Rack to 2.0.6 because a security issue. Now it is broken.
Any idea or issues that you have had with updating gems in Docker.

Comment: "broken" any errors?

Comment: + `Downloading actionpack-5.1.6 revealed dependencies not in the API or the lockfile (rack (~> 2.0)).`  

---

+ `Either installing with --full-index or running bundle update actionpack should fix the problem.`      

---

+ `bundler: command not found: rails`      

---

+ `Install missing gem executables with bundle install`